# How to display currency symbols in select list in cakephp with mysql database

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have currency codes and symbols in the a table

```
CURRENCIES(id, currency) VALUES('1', 'EUR (£)'), ('2', 'USD ($)') etc
```

but the euro and pound symbols do not show in the drop down list.
What could be the reason and how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bad encoding

Whenever none-ascii characters don't display correctly (or at all) the problem is encoding. Ensure that your application is using the same encoding (UTF8 unless there's a reason not to):

- In database table definitions
- In the database data (if there's existing data in the wrong encoding - it'll need recreating or correcting)
- In your application [database connection](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/database.php.default#L72)
- In your application [core config](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/core.php#L86)
- In your application [layout files](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp#L24)